# Does Corona SDK or Lua have an 'eval' function available?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I would like to have a dynamic variable name and want to be able to eval and get the value of it and was wondering if this was available. Example on how I want to use it.

```
audio.play(eval("readAloudPage"..page_num)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of a global variable is sought, then try `_G["readAloudPage"..page_num]`.

Or define

```
function eval(name)
   return _G[name]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic variable names must be table fields: the globals table which is named `_G`, or your own table if you don't want to use globals (usually the case). Example:

```
local yourDynVars = {}
yourDynVars["readAloudPage"..page_num] = ...
audio.play(yourDynVars["readAloudPage"..page_num])
print( yourDynVars.readAloudPage2 ) -- not dynamic; prints nil unless page_num was 2, above
```

If you replace `yourDynVars` table by `_G` the only difference is that in the last line you can access the var directly:

```
_G["readAloudPage"..page_num] = ...
audio.play(_G["readAloudPage"..page_num])
print( readAloudPage2 ) -- not dynamic; prints nil unless page_num was 2, above
```

Answer (score 1):

Lua's closest equivalent to `eval(code)` would be `loadstring(code)()`.

Notice `loadstring(code)` does not execute the `code`, it dynamically creates a function with it. Use `loadstring(code)()` to create and run it.

Comment: and the `code` would be something like `"return readAloudPage"..page_num`

Comment: It is locked in Corona

Comment: @500 not anymore!

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is lhf's solution to use `_G["readAloudPage"..page_num]`.

Lua provides [loadstring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) function to convert strings to executable functions, but this function is disabled in Corona SDK (and can only be used/accessed in debug environment).

Comment: Yes, it throws an error Corona Simulator[50857:507] ERROR: loadstring() is not available b/c the parser is not loaded.

Comment: There is not much you can do about it. There are command line options for the simulator to enable loadstring, but it only works in the simulator. You won't be able to use it in your application.

Comment: The Corona SDK now supports Lua 5.1's loadstring() at run-time and not only in debug.